# Visual Studio setup project running very slow

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-project

I have created a Visual Studio 2010 setup project, which contains two executable files and some additional xml files. The overall size is about 2mb and installing is just a simple copying to ProgramFiles with adding icons to desktop and start menu.

But it takes about 30 sec to install in fast computer and about 3-4 min in slow laptop. What could be the reason of it?

Comment: Try creating a verbose installation log to see which actions take a lot of time: http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/

Comment: It's not just you.. not only the installer is extremely clunky so is the overall Setup Project, of Visual Studio (even 2022). it's so clunky it's actually ridiculous to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what is taking so long on the laptop compared to the fast pc. My guess is that old hardware (eg HDD, Ram, etc) is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the operating system is creating a restore point.